# I want to retrive data in tabular form using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I have written the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-    scale=1.0">
        <title>contact.dat</title>
      <body>
      <div id="demo">
    <h2>Retrive data by ajax</h2>
    <button type="button" onclick="printdata()">Retrive data</button>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    function printdata() {
      const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML +=this.responseText;
      }
      xhttp.open("GET", "contact.dat");
      xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
      </body>
    
    <?php
    
    $fp = fopen('contact.dat', 'r');
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><th>Sr. No.</th><th>Name</th><th>Residence No.</th><th>Mob.
    no.</th><th>Address</th></tr>";
    while ($row = fscanf($fp, "%s %s %s %s %s")) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $r) {
            echo "<td>$r</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
    
    </html>
```

its showing me [image: this output]
I want to show data when I click on the button.
I'm new in both JavaScript as well as PHP.
is there any way to perform something like

```
if(isset(printdata();))
```

then run php code block???

Answer (score 1):

Here lies the wrong

```
/usr/bin/env /opt/jdk17/bin/java .... java.ASG6Ba
```

Probably the file that you try to execute is `ASG6Ba.java`.

The provided file `java.ASG6Ba` with the ending `ASG6Ba` makes no sense for java to be executed.

Also `java` is a prohibited name for packages in java and since the file provided is `java.ASG6Ba`, java thinks that `java` is a package name and then follows the class name `ASG6Ba`. This is the specific reason the error is thrown.

> Prohibited package name: java

This is also described in java [documentation in chapter 6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1)

> The first component of a package or module name **must not be the
> identifier java**. Package and module names that start with the
> identifier java are reserved for packages and modules of the Java SE
> Platform